# Let $I,J$ be ideals of $R$. Is $I\star J= \{ij\mid i\in I, j\in J\}$ an ideal of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**Attempt:**
We have that $0\in I\star J$ because $0\in I$. If we consider $ij\in I\star J$ and $c\in R$, then  $ijc\in I\star J$ as $J$ is a right ideal of $R$; $jc\in J$. In addition, $cij\in I\star J$ as $I$ is a left ideal of $R$; $ci\in I$. Suppose we have another element $hg\in I\star J$. We now need to show that
$$ij-hg\in I\star J$$
to declare $I\star J$ an ideal of $R$ by the ideal test. I have thought about employing some factorization technique, but have failed to do so. Might there be some special trick for this last part? Or am I mistaken in that there is exists a contradiction?

Any input appreciated.

**Edit:** As per my comment below, my attempted proof fails because the statement is not true. For a contradiction, consider $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and the ideal(s) $I=J=(x,y)$. Since $x,y\in (x,y)$, $I\star J$ is not closed under addition: $x^2+y^2$ is not real factorizable.

Comment: The result is false. You need to close it under summation to obtain an ideal.

Comment: If $a,b$ are distinct elements of $I$ and $c,d$ are distinct elements of $J$, there's no obvious way to simplify $ac+bd$. But $ac+bd$ must be in any ideal containing $I\star J$.  This should suggest that $I\star J$ is not itself an ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the product of two ideals $I, J$ is defined as the ideal *generated* by all elements of the form $ij$ with $i \in I$ and $j \in J$.

This set in your question is in general not an ideal. Here is a counterexample.

Take $R = \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I = J = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$.

We have $(1 + \sqrt{-5})\times(1 - \sqrt{-5}) = 6$ and $2 \times 2 = 4$ which are both in $I \star J$.

However, I claim that their difference $2$ is not an element of $I\star J$.

Suppose that $2 = (2a + (1 + \sqrt{-5})b)(2c + (1 + \sqrt{-5})d)$ with $a, b, c, d\in\Bbb Z$. We take norms of both sides and get $4 = ((2a + b)^2 + 5b^2)((2c + d)^2 + 5d^2)$. Clearly there are no integers $a, b, c, d$ satisfying this equation.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! Now that I think about it, might another contradiction also arise if we observe $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and the ideals $I=J=(x,y)$? Say, if we denote $ij=x^2$ and $hg=-y^2$, then $ij-hg=x^2+y^2$ is not an element of $I\star J$ because $x^2+y^2$ is not real factorizable, right?

Comment: Yes, this will also be a possible counterexample - actually much simpler than mine.

Comment: Another similar counterexample: take $R = \mathbb{Z}[x], I = \langle 2, x \rangle, J = \langle 3, x \rangle$.  Then both $2 \cdot x$ and $x \cdot 3$ are in $I \star J$ but their difference $x$ is not.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, also much simpler than my example. I somehow had the idea that a counterexample should definitely not be a PID, and hence I took a ring of integers with class number $> 1$.